# sum Data from column 1 where falls between range in column 2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm fairly new to PL-SQL so could use a bit of help.

Table#1 contains:

```
LoanIntersestRates
------------------
4.5
4.0
3.5
3.0
2.5
```

Table #2 Contains:

```
ActualInterestRate  LoanAmt
-----------------------------
4.6                 356258.00
4.7                 387958.25
2.6                 485658.25
3.65                500562.00
4.1                 434135.25
2.65                756254.02
4.5                 286325.02
```

What I need to do is get a sum of the loanAmt where the ActualInterestRate is Exactly what is in table one.
Also, Need to sum up the loadAmts where the actualInterestrate is 1-50 points above each of the LoanInterestRates, 50-100 points above each of the LoanInterestRates and 100+ points above each of the LoanInterestRates.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain with an example regarding the points (1-50),(50-100)

Comment: LoanInterestRate = 4.5
So now I need to sum the LoanAmts where ActualInterestrate is 1-50 points above 4.5 so anything between 4.5 and 5.0 
ie.4.6,4.7,4.8,4.9 etc...

Comment: @user3111964 What have you tried so far? Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query if you want to get the sum for rates mentioned in table 1

```
select lr.interest,sum(amount) from loaninterestrates lr, loaninterestamounts la
where lr.interest = la.interest
group by lr.interest
```

For step - 2 to find the sum for ranges use this

```
select la1.intrange,sum(la1.amount)from
(
select la.interest,la.amount,case when Remainder(la.interest*10,10) < 0 or Remainder(la.interest*10,10) = 5 
                  then to_char(FLOOR(la.interest) + 0.5) || '-' || to_char(FLOOR(la.interest) + 1.0)
            else to_char(FLOOR(la.interest)) || '-' || to_char(FLOOR(la.interest) + 0.5 )
            end as intrange
        from loaninterestamounts la

  ) la1
 group by la1.intrange
```

sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92f15/8

Answer (score 0):

hi I have some misunderstanding your question but please check my sql

```
with t1 as
 (select 4.5 as lir
    from dual
  union all
  select 4.0
    from dual
  union all
  select 3.5
    from dual
  union all
  select 3.0
    from dual
  union all
  select 2.5 from dual),
t2 as
 (select 4.6 as air, 356258.00 as la
    from dual
  union all
  select 4.7, 387958.25
    from dual
  union all
  select 2.6, 485658.25
    from dual
  union all
  select 3.65, 500562.00
    from dual
  union all
  select 4.1, 434135.25
    from dual
  union all
  select 2.65, 756254.02
    from dual
  union all
  select 4.5, 286325.02 from dual),
t1_d as
 (select lir as lir_low, lead(lir) over(order by lir) as lir_high from t1)
select t1_d.lir_low, sum(la) as sum_la
  from t1_d, t2
 where t2.air >= t1_d.lir_low
   and ((t2.air < t1_d.lir_high) or (t1_d.lir_high is null))
 group by t1_d.lir_low
```

Comment: Sorry if i didn't explain well enough, what are you misunderstanding? The actualinterestrates are going to be dynamic. I won't know what the values are.

Comment: problem in "Point" I do not understand what mean 1-50 for me it's look like 1.5 for example 4.5 -> 4.5 - 6.0 So i my sql I just find all periods for your data (check t1_d subselect)